# при попытке вывести на экран картинку выдает ошибку

Tags: flutter, dart

помогите решить проблему, при попытке открыть картинки с такой ссылкой `https://а-вкусно.рф/images/004/794/755/4794755/990xnoinc/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F.jpg` 
выдает ошибку 
`FormatException: %D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE.%D1%80%D1%84 is not a valid link-local address but contains %. Scope id should be used as part of link-local address. (at character 1)`

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "https://а-вкусно.рф/images/004/794/755/4794755/990xnoinc/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F.jpg",
        imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: imageProvider,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                colorFilter:
                    ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red, BlendMode.colorBurn)),
          ),
        ),
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
      )
```

Comment: Кодировать кириллицу в Punycode
тут только в этом дело

Comment: @Yamich и получить такую ссылку: `https://-./images/004/794/755/4794755/990xnoinc/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F.jpg-9c1g7h37a7j4d1k8d3kse`, не поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению Flutter не поддерживает кириллические ссылки и не ясно когда будет поддерживать. Как вариант можно использовать:

1. Использовать латинские ссылки.
2. Использовать Base64 Image.

Comment: это касается любой части урла (например, название картинки)?

Comment: @Дмытрык именно после домена. Например: `https://а-вкусно.рф/` эту часть он обрабатывает без проблем, так как трансформирует её в `https://xn----7sbh6apgtp.xn--p1ai/`. А все что дальше на кириллице он ругается на `%`, так как не может расшифровать и понять. Что интересно если взять такую ссылку:`https://а-вкусно.рф/images/004/794/755/4794755/990xnoinc/Аппетитная.jpg` он трансформирует её в такой вид `https://а-вкусно.рф/images/004/794/755/4794755/990xnoinc/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F.jpg`

Comment: просто ссылки на картинки получаю из базы данных, видимо, придется ждать

Answer (score 1):

Как обходной путь для домена можно использовать replaceAll. У меня такая же была ошибка. Я сделал так для домена и все заработало

```
URL.replaceAll('а-вкусно.рф', 'xn----7sbh6apgtp.xn--p1ai')
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за столь долгий ответ, но нет. Минусы я вам не ставил. Ваш ответ ясен и тактичен. Я лишь предложил свой, который помог мне в почти такой же проблеме.

Comment: Извиняюсь за свой наезд на вас. Время так совпало что я подумал на вас) Вашему ответу тоже есть место для данного вопроса, я надеюсь он кому-то поможет)